# A function inside a function?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, jquery-animate

I'm currently learning how to work with Canvas, but I'm currently stuck trying to put a function inside a class.

```
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var disc = function(x,y,h,w,c1,c2,ctx){
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.h=h;
  this.w=w;
  this.c1=c1;
  this.c2=c2;
  this.ctx=ctx;

}

disc.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.ctx.fillStyle=this.c1;
  this.ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h/2);
  this.ctx.fillStyle=this.c2;
  this.ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y+this.h/2,this.w,this.h/2);
}

disc.prototype.erase = function() {
  this.ctx.clearRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
}


d1 = new disc(100,100,20,40,"#ff0000","#0000ff",ctx);

 var dx=1;
 var dy=1;

 function animate() {
      d1.erase();
      d1.x = d1.x + dx;
      d1.y = d1.y + dy;
      if ( d1.x>=500 || d1.x < 50)  { dx = dx * -1; d1.y = 40;}
      d1.draw();

  }

setInterval(animate,1);


</script>
```

How would I move the animate function inside the disc function itself?
I've tried inserting this into the disc function:

```
  var dx=1;
  var dy=1;
  animate = function() {
      this.erase();
      this.x = this.x + dx;
      this.y = this.y + dy;
      if ( this.x>=500 || this.x < 50)  { dx = dx * -1; this.y = 40;}
      this.draw();
   }
 this.animate = animate;
```

as well as changing

```
setInterval(d1.animate,1);
```

but it gives me

```
caught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'erase'
```

Comment: The problem is that within your `d1.animate()` function `this` is the global object (`Window`) when your function is called by `setInterval`. Try `setInterval(function(){d1.animate();},1);` or `setInterval(d1.animate.bind(d1),1);` instead. And speaking of `setInterval`, do you really need a 1ms delay? The browser will round that up to 4ms, but even that is way smaller than you need for a smooth animation (20ms will give you 50fps).

Comment: As a side not, the technical term for a function within a function is funception. It is highly advisable that you do now go more than three levels deep, otherwise you will wind up on the shores of your.. something.

Comment: "Funception"? @davidisawesome you _are_ awesome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the function to the `prototype` of `disc`, like below:

```
disc.prototype.animate = function(dx, dy) {
      this.erase();
      this.x = this.x + dx;
      this.y = this.y + dy;
      if ( this.x>=500 || this.x < 50)  { dx = dx * -1; this.y = 40;}
      this.draw();
};

setInterval(function() {
  d1.animate(1, 1);
},1);
```

Comment: ooohhhh! so that's what it means to make it in the class

Comment: Adding to the prototype rather than directly is sensible, but it's not why the code in the question didn't work (see my comment above).

Comment: The main problem is in the `setInterval` part. You can add the function directly via `this`, though adding to the prototype is a more common practice, but this isn't the main cause to the failure.